# Select values compared with a calculated output (an average of another table)

Tags: mysql, sql, where-clause, average

Hopefully i can explain this properly, 
My output currently shows IDs and an average for a bunch of results for each ID on another table. It also grabs what the average of these results should be, and plate number..

NOW, what i would like to do is, set a threshold.. so only show me IDs of which average are less then 50% of the what they should be....

This is my code currently

```
select k.ncr_identifier, avg(j.total_mass) as MassTotalAvg, l.TOTAL_COMBINATION_MASS , k.plate_number
From iapm_mass_data j
inner join iapm_data_link k on j.record_id = k.mass_record_id
inner join iacd_ncr_sdtcm_rec l on  k.ncr_record_id = l.NCR_ID
Where k.ivu_date >= date '2015-03-01' 
and k.ivu_date <= date '2015-03-31'
and l.VEHICLE_CATEGORY_CODE = '12'
group by k.ncr_identifier
```

I tried to chuck this like in

```
and l.TOTAL_COMBINATION_MASS < 0.5(avg(j.total_mass))
```

But didnt seem to like it, any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

For that condition, you need to use Having keyword. Please try this:

```
select k.ncr_identifier, avg(j.total_mass) as MassTotalAvg, l.TOTAL_COMBINATION_MASS , k.plate_number
From iapm_mass_data j
inner join iapm_data_link k on j.record_id = k.mass_record_id
inner join iacd_ncr_sdtcm_rec l on  k.ncr_record_id = l.NCR_ID
Where k.ivu_date >= date '2015-03-01' 
and k.ivu_date <= date '2015-03-31'
and l.VEHICLE_CATEGORY_CODE = '12'
group by k.ncr_identifier, l.TOTAL_COMBINATION_MASS , k.plate_number
having l.TOTAL_COMBINATION_MASS < 0.5(avg(j.total_mass))
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
select k.ncr_identifier, avg(j.total_mass) as MassTotalAvg, l.TOTAL_COMBINATION_MASS , k.plate_number
    From iapm_mass_data j
        inner join iapm_data_link k on j.record_id = k.mass_record_id
        inner join iacd_ncr_sdtcm_rec l on  k.ncr_record_id = l.NCR_ID
    Where k.ivu_date >= date '2015-03-01' 
        and k.ivu_date <= date '2015-03-31'
        and l.VEHICLE_CATEGORY_CODE = '12'
    group by k.ncr_identifier, l.TOTAL_COMBINATION_MASS , k.plate_number
    having l.TOTAL_COMBINATION_MASS < 0.5*avg(j.total_mass)
```

Note that you need to have all non-aggregated fields of select-list to be mentioned in the "group by" clause.

Comment: actually mysql lets you get away without specifying all non aggregated fields in the group by. but you have to be careful that any such fields all have the same value, or your results will be indeterminate

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the response, but MySQL dosnt seem to like it, getting the error 

"You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near '(avg(j.total_mass))' at line 9"

Comment: Hey guys, thanks for the response, odd but MySQL didnt like 0.5(avg(j.total_mass), but was happy with 0.5*avg(j.total_mass).. so seems to be working, thanks again

Comment: It was not odd!     "*" was missing.